# Converter does not work correctly

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, converters, managed-bean

Guys my problem is that I get this error when I load the page. I'm trying to use a converter for my selectOneMenu field, it must be simple but I can't find the solution. There are data in the Database, and no error log.

[image]

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Tag.class)//Tag is the class where I get my Tag.
public class ConverteGadoTag implements Converter {

@Inject
private TagsRep tagsRep; //this is my repository

@Override    //this is BalusC code.
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,  String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a valid ID number: " + value);
        }



        Long id = new Long(value);
        return tagsRep.porId(id);
        // You may want to perform an additional check if it didn't return null
        // and otherwise throw ConverterException with "unknown Product ID".
    }

    @Override    
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {        
        if (value == null) {
            return null; // Or an empty string, can also.
        }

        if (!(value instanceof Tag)) {
            throw new ConverterException("The value is not a valid Product: " + value);
        }

        Long id = ((Tag)value).getTagId();
        return (id != null) ? String.valueOf(id) : null;
    }

}
```

My xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p ="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

<ui:define name="titulo">Novo Gado</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="gado" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado}" converter="# {converteGadoTag}"/>
    <f:event listener="#{cadastroGadoBean.inicializar}"  type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>


<h:form>
    <h1>Novo Gado</h1>

    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/gado/CadastroGado"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroGadoBean.salvar}" update="@form"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>

    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top:  20px" 
    columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

        <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="gadoTipo"/>
        <p:inputText id="gadoTipo" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoTipo}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Peso" for="gadoPeso"/>
        <p:inputText id="gadoPeso" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoPeso}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Sexo" for="sexo"/>
        <p:inputText id="sexo" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.sexo}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Nascimento" for="gadoNasc"/>
        <p:calendar id="gadoNasc" size="10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoNasc}" />

        <p:outputLabel value="Raça" for="gadoRaca"/>
        <p:inputText id="gadoRaca" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoRaca}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Finalidade do Gado" for="gadoFinalidade"/>
        <p:inputText id="gadoFinalidade" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoFinalidade}"/>


        <p:outputLabel value="Status" for="gadoStatus"/>
        <p:inputText id="gadoStatus" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoStatus}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Ultima Latitude" for="ultimaLat"/>
        <p:inputText id="ultimaLat" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.ultimaLat}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Ultima Longitude" for="ultimaLong"/>
        <p:inputText id="ultimaLong" size="60" maxlength="80"
        value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.ultimaLong}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Tag"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu title="Selecione a tag" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.tag}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroGadoBean.listTags}"  var="tag"
                itemValue="#{tag}" itemLabel="#{tag.descricao}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: *then I used BalusC's code and it worked* So use Balus' code.

Comment: Sorry about that. B4 I use his code there was another error. Now I get this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code as follows...

Java Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("tagConverter")
public class ConverteGadoTag implements Converter {
```

XHTML:

```
<p:selectOneMenu title="Selecione a tag" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.tag}" converter="tagConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroGadoBean.listTags}"  var="tag"
                itemValue="#{tag}" itemLabel="#{tag.descricao}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Just define the converter to use explicitly.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I've already tried and it does not get right. Now I have a nullPointerException in this line in getAsString method: 

return ((Tag) value).getTagId().toString();

Comment: Was `tagId` not set? Try to debug. How is the class `Tag` looking like?

Comment: I resolved that error message from the beginning, now, it saves all the fields in the DB except the tagId. No error log. 

My class Tag has its atributes and the id is like that(IDK if I can post code here in comments, if not tellme)


 `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tag_sequence")
 @Column(name = "tag_id")
 public Long getTagId() {
  return tagId;
 }`

The Class Gado:
`private Tag tag;
...
@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
 public Tag getTag() {
  return tag;
 }`